# Is it a good idea to have multiple D3DImage (say 5) elements in a WPF application?

Tags: .net, wpf, direct3d

Our app requires to show multiple videos and some animation might be on top of video elements. By having multiple D3DImage elements CPU usage was very high.

What are the possible ways to solve this problem, can think of following?

1. Will using VisualHost mechanism solve this problem. Each D3DImage element is contained in VisualHost.
2. Do some D3D mixing and make D3DImage element as one.

Any other better ideas.

Comment: Basically playing multiple videos is CPU/GPU intensive by itself. Combining everything in one D3DImage will reduce WPF/D3D interop overhead but not decoding and rendering time. Using VisualHost may reduce slightly interop issues but your PC still have to decode multiple videos. Do you have dedicated graphics card?

Comment: Yes, dedicated graphics is expected.

Comment: Some answer from [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/27e22c48-14be-4f5c-9a61-f16f9fc2ab7d/d3dimage-maximum-instances?forum=wpf)

Comment: Also from [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/performance-considerations-for-direct3d9-and-wpf-interoperability?redirectedfrom=MSDN). **Use D3DImage Sparingly
Direct3D9 content hosted in a D3DImage instance does not render as fast as in a pure Direct3D application. Copying the surface and flushing the command buffer can be costly operations. As the number of D3DImage instances increases, more flushing occurs, and performance degrades. Therefore, you should use D3DImage sparingly.**